# Why does calling `detach` cause R to "forget" functions?

Tags: r

Sometimes I use `attach` with some subset terms to work with odd dimensions of study data. To prevent "masking" variables in the environment (really the warning message itself) I simply call `detach()` to just remove whatever dataset I was working with from the R search path. When I get muddled in scripting, I may end up calling `detach` a few times. Well, interestingly if I call it enough, R removes functions that are loaded at start-up as part of packages like from `utils`, `stats`, and `graphics`. Why does "detach" remove these functions?

Comment: `detach` removes `search()[2]`. So do it enough times and you'll detach everything. You might want to consider changing your workflow. Working with `attach` is discouraged, but using `detach` in this fashion is even worse :)

Comment: `with` and `transform` might be of interest to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> R removes base functions from the search path, like `plot` and `?` and so on.

These functions that were removed are often called “base” functions but they are not part of the actual ‹base› package. Rather, `plot` is from the package ‹graphics›, and `?` is from the package ‹utils›, both of which are part of the [R default packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Default-packages), and are therefore attached by default. Both packages are attached *after* `package:base`, and you’re accidentally detaching these packages with your too many `detach` calls (`package:base` itself *cannot* be detached; this is important because if it were detached, you couldn’t reattach it: the functions necessary for that are inside `package:base`).

To expand on this, `attach` and `detach` are *usually* used in conjunction with package environments rather than data sets: to enable the uses functions from a package without explicitly typing the package name (e.g. `graphics::plot`), the `library` function attaches these packages. When loading R, some packages are attached by default. You can find more information about this in Hadley Wickham’s [*Advanced R*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

As you noticed, you can also attach and detach data sets. However, this is generally discouraged (quite strongly, in fact). Instead, you can use data transformation functions from the base package (e.g. `with` and `transform`, as noted by Moody_Mudskipper in a comment) or from data manipulation package ([‹dplyr›](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) is state of the art; an alternative is [‹data.table›](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)).

Comment: @AdamO I’m not entirely happy with this: the answer stays the same but now half of it doesn’t make sense given the changed wording of the question.

Comment: @Konrad to be fair,  we often talk about "base packageS",  "base R"... so i think calling functions from package `utils` etc base functions is Ok, how else can we call them in less than 6 words ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You are *entirely* right, and since this is such a common name I’ll change the wording.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't mean to undercut you. I had to edit my question to get an answer that made sense to me. Part of making sense is correcting my understanding where it's wrong. I see now attach/detach has a conflated usage: "usually for datasets" as R help states, but also for packages. I have some remaining confusion about why attach was ever a useful and or necessary part of a namespace.